# How to add data to an array from custom uitableviewcell's textfield after editing done

Tags: uitableview, nsmutablearray, uitextfield

I'm creating customUiTableViewCells in which each has a textfield in a uitableview in which every section is different to each other .In one section I can add and delete any no.of cells.While scrolling if the rows reaching out the boundary of uitableview(ie., not visible )the data given in that cell is not taking. In my code  when I'm pressing a button i'm reading data from the tableview, Now i got an idea like after editing every row I want the data to store in some array.So that when i'm pressing a button I should read data from this array not the cells.Please give me any suggestions so,that I can move forward. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure you change your CellIdentifier in cellForRowAtIndexPath: to:

```
NSString *CellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"S%1dR%1d",indexPath.section,indexPath.row];
```

without static.

Then your TextFields keep the data to store it afterwards.